# Firebase and the Google OAuth consent screen

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I have a web app developed using Firebase. It is hosted by Firebase and my domain is connected to it. It uses Google as an identity provider for authentication. However, when signing-in via a popup, the Google 'OAuth consent screen' provides a link direct to the Firebase project.

Is there a way to make the link point to the associated web site?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there is an easy solution for my scenario. Just needed to set the authDomain parameter of config passed to the firebase.initializeApp() method to my domain (rather than the default <project-name>.firebaseapp.com value). Initially this will cause the OAuth screen to throw an error but it includes a link to a configuration page where I needed to add https://<my-domain>/_auth/handler to the list of authorization handlers.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I would've found this without your tip.